# Добавить Header с TabLayout в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Знаю, что добавляют `Header`, `Footer` и вообще различные кастомные `item` в адаптер `RecyclerView`, но не знаю добавляют ли в `Header` разметку `TabLayout` с последующим переключением табов, которые будут менять содержимое `RecyclerView` в зависимости от таба, если нажал **1** таб **Новости** то ниже `Header` появляются новости, нажал **2** таб **Биография** новости исчезли, появилась биография.

Если `Header` использовать вне `RecyclerView`, то необходимо использовать `NestedScrollView` внутри которого `RecyclerView`, но не получается настроить, у `RecyclerView` появляется автоскролл, а в скролле настроен подгружаемый адаптер, соотвественно появляется неуправляемая подгрузка. Ну и все в один голос говорят, что нельзя использовать `RecyclerView` в `NestedScrollView`.

Используют ли `Header` с `TabLayout` в `RecyclerView`?

Макет экрана, примерно, такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У `RecyclerView` как таковых хедеров нет. Это будет просто обычный итем с нулевой позицией и другим `viewType`. Пихать туда табы выглядит очень странным решением. Делайте табы отдельно от `RecyclerView`. Только зачем в этом случае вам `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: Да я в курсе, что хедер это обычный итем. Макет экрана добавил, должно все вместе сколлиться, без всякой липкости и эффектов материала, хедер должен просто уйти вверх как и обычный итем RecyclerView. Сейчас реализовал это в NestedScrollView, но имею проблемы с автоскроллом RecyclerView.

Comment: Я думаю `CollapsingToolbarLayout` справится с задачей без скрол вью. Только нужно будет поэксперементировать с `app:layout_scrollFlags`

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю, но мне кажется все что касается CoordinatorLayout , CollapsingToolbarLayout дает материальные эффекты.